# Is it possible to ignore AudioFocus changes in android?

Tags: android, audio

Is it possible to allow an app to continue to play sound if there is a permanent loss in audio focus? I'm doing a little pre development research because i want to make a program that plays certain sounds while another app has control over the audio output. e.g. Music player, Netflix, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. But ideally you shouldn't be doing it unless it is not disturbing the end user. It may result in your app being discarded by end user. Make sure end user's general expectations are considered and met.